# regular expression to capture N words at start of a line without effecting next line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large csv file and I need to capture the first few words of a line (6 or less). I'm using replace in notepad++ and I have this regexp.

```
^((\w+\S+)\s+){1,6}.*$     (My 'replace with' text is \1...)
```

My problem is if a line has less than 6 words it will effect the next line.

eg: if I run the replace on this text:

```
one two three four five six
one two three four
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
```

What I get is this result:

```
one two three four five six...
one two three four
one two...
one two three four five six...
```

This is the result I'm after:

```
one two three four five six...
one two three four...
one two three four five six...
one two three four five six...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But *why* are you using the wrong tool for the job? CSV parsers exist in lots of places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\s` includes newline. Try `(?:(?!\n)\s)` or `[^\S\n]` instead:

```
^((\w+\S+)[^\S\n]+){1,6}.*$
```

Also, this includes the following space, so the rows with exactly six words will not be matched. Try this:

```
^((?:\w+\S*)(?:[^\S\n]+(\w+\S*)){0,5}).*$
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

Find what: `^((?:\S+\h){6}).*$`
Replace with: `$1`

This will remove everything that is present after the sixth word. Line with less than 6 words will be left as is.

`\h` stands for horizontal white space.
`\w+\S+` can be reduce to `\S+`, if it doesn't fit your needs, keep `\w+\S+`

Make sure you have NOT checked `dot matches newline`